# Set up a QBuffer as a FIFO with a restricted size ? QT

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qt5

I have a continuous audio stream flow from which I'd like to keep only the last 50 seconds.

I do it like so for now but I have issues:

1. The buffer grows beyond 50 seconds. I tried to use resize on a `QByteArray` to get closer from a FIFO , but it doesn't seem to care much about it and continue to grow so I guess I misunderstood the doc.
2. The sound get suddenly ugly when we pass the 15 sec -> I have no clue why the sound suddenly rips (if I load a 5min local sound in the same buffer, everything works great).
3. Last, but not least of course, the buffer doesn't behave like a FIFO and this is what I'm looking for to keep only the last 50sec

Here is my code: (Windows10 - Qt5)

```
buffer = new QBuffer;
arr = new QByteArray; 
arr->resize(200000);
buffer->setData(*arr); // buffer->setBuffer(*arr);
buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

dataStream.setDevice(buffer); ` 

m_player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
m_player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer);

[...]

connect(m_player, &QMediaPlayer::durationChanged, this, &MainWindow::durationChanged);
connect(m_player, &QMediaPlayer::positionChanged, this, &MainWindow::positionChanged);
```

I refresh the buffer duration in the latest slot.
So the buffer gets bigger than 50sec of course and the sound get chopped after 15 sec.

Does anyone know how to set up a FIFO buffer with a restricted size with Qt?

----------------------------------------------------------           EDIT        ------------------------------------------------------------------

I found this to get closer but I miss something in it :

```
//.cpp :


#define SAMPLE_RATE 22050
#define CHANNELS 1
#define SAMPLE_SIZE 16
#define SAMPLE_TYPE SignedInt

myAudio::myAudio()
{
formatIn.setSampleRate(SAMPLE_RATE);
formatIn.setChannelCount(CHANNELS);
formatIn.setSampleSize(SAMPLE_SIZE);
[...]
formatIn.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
formatIn.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SAMPLE_TYPE);

formatOut. //same than formatIn
[...]

//configure device
 audioOut = new QAudioOutput(deviceOut,formatOut,0);
 audioIn  = new QAudioInput (deviceIn, formatIn,0);


  buff.resize(0x10000);   //create a rx buffer

  pbuff=buff.data();       //get the buff address;
  RXbuff=0;                //set RX buffer pointer

  qDebug()<<"File open"<<open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
  qDebug()<<"is device Sequential="<<isSequential();
  audioIn->start(this); //start reading device

  audioOut->setVolume(0.5);  //volume 0 to 1.0
  audioOut->start(this);    //start writing to device
}

//QIODevice Class (Protected Functions)This function is called by QIODevice.
//send to output(Speaker)

qint64 myAudio::readData(char *data, qint64 len)
{
static quint64 TXbuff=0;
qint64 total = 0;
while (len > total  && RXbuff>TXbuff)//write and synchonise buffers
   {
     //write data to speaker
    memcpy(&data[total],&pbuff[TXbuff%0x10000], 2);    //copy 2 Bytes
    TXbuff+=2; //point to next buffer 16 bit location
    total+=2;
   }
return total;  //the reset interval
}


//audio input (from Microphone)
qint64 myAudio::writeData(const char *data, qint64 len)
{
int total=0;
while (len > total)
   {
    memcpy(&pbuff[RXbuff%0x10000],&data[total], 2); //write 2Bytes into 
circular buffer(64K)
    RXbuff+=2; //next 16bit buffer location
    total+=2;  //next data location
  }
 return (total); //return total number of bytes received
}

qint64 myAudio::bytesAvailable() const{return 0;}
```

What I miss is pretty basic... does anyone know When/How are the methods called ?!

Comment: What do you mean by "having a continuous data stream"? Where is the data coming from? How are you adding it to the buffer? As far as stream buffering goes, you'd need a custom solution for that.

Comment: In the current case it's a data stream that comes from internet; I'm adding it to the buffer with a QDataStream ` dataStream.setDevice(buffer); ` The thing is that I have no idea how to perform such a buffer (I'd know how to create a FIFO but not how to link each chunk of data to it's block nor how to allow the Qt's player to seek in it. Would you have a ressource exemple by chance so i could get inspired from ?

Comment: I'll write something up for you when I find time.

Comment: @ Kuba Ober https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCtzkaL2t_Y except the love thing